# facebook logout error

Tags: php, facebook, oauth-2.0

i am trying to use the facebook login for the site https://www.mysite.com

on www.mysite.com/login.php i print a facebook login button using Javascript SDK.
login works correctly.

in the logged pages i print a logout button using:

```
require_once 'oauth2/facebook/facebook.php';
require 'admin/inc/facebook.inc.php'; //contains setting as secret sky, app id, etc

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $fb_app_id,
'secret' => $fb_secret_key
));

$fb_user=null;
$fb_user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($fb_user) {

$fb_user_profile=$facebook->destroySession();

$params = array( 'next' => 'https://www.mysite.com/logout.php' );

echo="<a href=\"".$facebook->getLogoutUrl($params))."\" >"."logout"."</a>";
}

else echo="<a href=\"/logout.php\" >"."logout"."</a>";
```

but when i press logout it redirects just to www.facebook.com/home.php

i tried to use Logout but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is calling `Facebook::destroySession` before building the logout URL.

`destroySession` clears the access token, but the access token is needed to build a working logout URL.